# Android camera image not uploaded to server . Using Multipart data Http post

Tags: android, image, upload, android-camera, multipart

I am trying to upload image from camera and gallery using multipart data http post using volley, but the image taken from camera is not getting uploaded whereas from the gallery is uploaded.

```
 private void startCamera() {

    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

 }
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                previewCapturedImage();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"User cancelled image capture",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
 }

 private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);
        filePath=fileUri.getPath();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);

        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, options.outWidth, options.outHeight, matrix, true);

        postImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
        ((TextView)appView.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public  void postFeed(String commentString){
    RequestQueue mqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("text",commentString);
    params.put("user_id",SettingsHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getPreference("id"));
    TSUServerRequest.postFeed(getActivity(),mqueue,params,new File(filePath),new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            Log.d("a","bscljk");
            filePath="";
            fileUri= null;
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();

        }
    });


  public static void postFeed(Context context,RequestQueue queue,Map<String, String> params,File file,
                            Listener<String> listener, ErrorListener errorListener){
    if (TSUServerRequest.checkForConnection(context)) {
        String url =API_CREATE_POST;
        MultiPartRequest myReq = new MultiPartRequest(url,errorListener,listener,file,params);
        queue.add(myReq);
        queue.start();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet!Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

////MultipartRequest.java

```
public class MultiPartRequest extends Request<String> {

MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
HttpEntity httpentity;
private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "picture";

private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private final File mFilePart;
private final Map<String, String> mStringPart;

public MultiPartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
                        Response.Listener<String> listener, File file,
                        Map<String, String> mStringPart) {
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mFilePart = file;
    this.mStringPart = mStringPart;
    entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    buildMultipartEntity();
}

public void addStringBody(String param, String value) {
    mStringPart.put(param, value);
}

private void buildMultipartEntity() {
    entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart));
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringPart.entrySet()) {
        entity.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return httpentity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        httpentity = entity.build();
        httpentity.writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason image was not getting uploaded was size.
Image file immediately taken from camera is too big in size and hence needs to be compressed.
The same file when picked from gallery gets uploaded because gallery internally compresses the files.

```
public File compress(){

    File file = new File(filePath);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath());
        if(flagCamera==1) {
            flagCamera=0;
            compressedFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/compressed" + file.getName());
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(compressedFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70,out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }else{
            return file;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return compressedFile;

}

public void postFeed(String commentString) {
    RequestQueue mqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("access_token", SettingsHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getPreference("auth_token"));
    params.put("text", commentString);
    params.put("user_id", SettingsHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getPreference("id"));
    params.put("privacy", Integer.toString(1));
    TSUServerRequest.postFeed(getActivity(), mqueue, params, compress(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            Log.d("a", "bscljk");
            filePath = "";
            fileUri = null;
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: any idea about my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req